# Mongoose populate does not populate with all the documents matching the criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I have a nodeJS application and a mongoDB database and I am using Mongoose to model the DB. One of the functions of the application is to store the courses in the database and then fetch it. The first time I call this API it always fetches one document less than what it should return but for subsequent calls, it fetches all the documents that match.

> 1. First Call, bulkCreate(course A) =>  saves A in  the database => console logs empty array []
> 2. Second Call , bulkCreate(course B) => saves B in the database => console logs [A,B]

I am not sure what is going here. I think it is something to do with fetching the result before it's populated in the database but for that, I have an await. I may be wrong though. Below is the code snippet.

```
async bulkCreateCourses(req, res, next) {  
  try {
    const courses = req.body.courses || []
    const institutionName = req.body.institutionName

    for (let course of courses) {
      const newCourse = await Course.create({
        name: course.name,
        description: course.description,
        location: course.location,
        credits: course.credits,

      })

      await Institution.findOneAndUpdate({
        name: institutionName
      }, {
        $push: {
          courses: newCourse
        }
      }, {
        new: true
      })
    }   
  }    
  const selectedInstitution = await Institution
  .findOne({
    name: institutionName
  })    .populate({     
    path: 'courses',
    match: {
      location: 'Plant Hall',
      credits: 4     
    }    
  })    console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedInstitution.courses, null, 2))
}
```